# execute commands with curly brackets on bash

Tags: bash, curly-brackets

I would like to know why the following command is not working in Bash and how it's possible to make it run:

```
/etc/init.d/{httpd,nscd} status
```

Thanks

Comment: learn to use the `set -vx` feature of the cmd line to see how cmds are being executed. you use `set +vx` to turn it off. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command doesn't work because it'd execute:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd /etc/init.d/nscd status
```

One way of achieving what you want would be to make use of a loop:

```
for util in /etc/init.d/{httpd,nscd} ; do
  ${util} status
done
```

Comment: Is there a one-line alternative for this without a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

That does not work because it only expands the the path.
Try this.

```
$ echo  /etc/init.d/{httpd,nscd} status

$ /etc/init.d/httpd /etc/init.d/nscd status
```